# GraphQL-Ruby. Time type

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, time, graphql, graphql-ruby

Per GraphQL wiki I can see that there is the only DateTime type: [Link](https://graphql-ruby.org/api-doc/1.8.7/GraphQL/Types/ISO8601DateTime.html)

As far as I understood to make only time there should be written additional scalar for that, but I do not have any clue how maybe somebody had already done that and could share his/her ideas? :)

As currently if I will use ISO8601DateTime I don't think it will work out as I'm using time column in database same as in ruby

Answer (score 0):

You can look into this [blog post on how to create a custom scalar](https://www.abhaynikam.me/posts/custom-scalar-in-graphql-ruby/) in GraphQL Ruby and it actually shows exactly how to do a time scalar.